# Are there any services which can monitor my website, if site is down, reboot my ec2 instance?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, amazon-ec2, monitoring

I have a micro instance on EC2, and I deployed a wordpress website on it. But the site will be down about every two days because mysql is killed, so visitors get "500 Internal Server Error".
And I need log in AWS, and reboot the instance. I know I should optimize the apache configuration, but rebooting the instance will be a simple solution.
I'm using a service which can monitor my website, and when site is down, they will send me a email, but they can't reboot the EC2 instance.

I configure the apache like below, it works now:

```
StartServers       1
MinSpareServers    1
MaxSpareServers    5
MaxClients        10
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can create a bash, and put it in /etc/cron.hourly to run it every hour.

Here is the content of bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Replace MYSQL_PORT with the real port number.
netstat -na | grep LISTEN | grep MYSQL_PORT
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
  reboot
fi
```

Don't forget to make it executable just like the below.

```
chmod 0755 /etc/cron.hourly/monitor_mysql.sh
```

Moreover you can make it check more frequently by create a file in /etc/cron.d/ like the below to check every 5 minutes.

```
# vi /etc/cron.d/monitor_mysql
*/5 * * * *     root /path/to/monitor_mysql.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution with any open source tool you can always try Nagios. Which does the monitoring as well as restarting of the failed services but with some configuration effort. You can refer [Nagios Site](http://www.nagios.org/) [Nagios Configuration](http://bobcares.com/blog/?p=67)

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong if you need to reboot every few days. I don't think it's your Apache configuration, but lots of other things can be wrong.

You can use the reboot script, but you should also monitor your uptime (with a service like [www.downnotifier.com](http://www.downnotifier.com)) en you might think about a reinstall if you don't reach an 99,7% uptime.